# Solving a simple function with step and which outputs max value & argument of a function

Tags: python, loops, math, range

I am writing a program which solves a function in an interval 0:9 where step size is 0.005. This program requires 1800 calculations and a way to find the max value of a function and x argument which was used.

What would be the recommended way and loops to use in order calculate function 1800 times (9/0.005), find the max value of it and output related argument value which was used in calculation for the max value?

My idea was that there should be 2 lists generated, one for the range/interval (1800 items) and other for calculated values (also 1800). Which would then find max in 'calculated array' and related x argument in the other array, using list index or some other method..

```
from operator import itemgetter
import math

myfile = open("result.txt", "w")
data = []
step=0.005
rng=9

lim=rng/step
print(lim)

xs=[x * step for x in range(rng)]

lim_int=int(lim)
print(xs)

for i in range(lim_int):
    num=itemgetter(i)(xs)
    x=math.sin(num)* math.exp(-num/100)
    print(i, x)
    data.append(x)

for i in range(rng):
    text = str(i)
    text2 = str(data[i])
    print(text, text2)
    myfile.write(text + ' ' + text2 + '\n')

i=1
while i < rng:
    i=i+1
    num2=itemgetter(i)(xs)
    v=math.sin(num2)* math.exp(-num2/100)
    if v==max(data):
        arg=num2
        break

print('largest function value', max(data))
print('function argument value used', arg)
myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is the widely used performant package for this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 9, 0.005)
f = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/100)

print("max is: ", np.max(f))
print("index of max is: ", np.argmax(f))
```

output:

```
max is:  0.98446367206362
index of max is:  312
```

If for some reason you want a native python solution (without using list methods `max` and `index`), you can do something like this:

```
step = 0.005
rng = 9
lim = int(rng/step)
x = [x_i*step for x_i in range(lim + 1)]
f = [math.exp(-x_i/100)*math.sin(x_i) for x_i in x]

max_ind = 0
f_max = f[max_ind]

for j, f_x in enumerate(f):
    if f_x > f_max:
        f_max = f_x
        max_ind = j
```

Comment: Thanks but it requires additional numpy install. I was looking a way to do this algorithmically.